# install sencha-touch 2.1 on mac

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd

I need to install sencha touch 2.1 on my mac but I can't…

i follow this guide

```
 http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2
```

so i installed sencha cmd and i copy the sencha-sdk folder in the www/ directory of apache.. if i do:

```
localhost/sencha-skd
```

on my browser i see the docs of sencha, so the server works fine..

but from the terminal if I write the command

```
sencha
```

i get

```
-bash: sencha: command not found
```

and this happend in every folder…

somebody can help me?
thanks a lot

Comment: Have you installed the [Sencha SDk Tools](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools) ? try the fullpath path/to/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha

Comment: i will try! thanks! 
that wasn't write in the guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download and install Sencha Cmd : http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Then ensure that the path for Sencha Cmd is in your `.bash_profile`:

`export PATH=/path/to/Sencha/cmd/3.0.0.250:$PATH`(it will be located in you your 'bin' directory)

Save your `.bash_profile` and restart Terminal.

**Edit:**
You can also try adding the path to your `.bashrc` as well. Then restart your terminal and try running `sencha` again.

Lastly to verify that Sencha Cmd is in your path do `echo $PATH`.

Comment: is normal that the .bash_profile was a empty file?

i added: export PATH=/User/francesco/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250:$PATH

but still doesn't work

Comment: you need to restart your terminal after doing that.

Comment: what error are you getting? Can you open your terminal and do `echo $PATH`. and show me what's the output.

Comment: this is the output: "/User/francesco/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"

Comment: It looks like its in your path. I don't know why you are still getting that error.

Comment: If you have the old version of the SDK Tools, try uninstalling it and removing it from your path.

Comment: now the sencha command works.. but if i do "sencha app create MyApp ../MyApp"
i get: "Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[ERR]  No such property : 'create'"

Comment: ok, "create" was a old command.. the new is "sencha generate app MyAppName /path/to/MyAppName"

Answer (score 0):

The Sencha Touch Sdk contains only the classes which contains the framework, plus examples and docs.
If you want to generate an app, compile it, etc. using the Sencha command from a terminal, you need to install the Sencha Cmd then.
That's a different product.

You can read more at the following guide:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command

And download the latest version from here:
http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Comment: i put the skd in Documents/progetti/sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl
and i installed senchaCmd in Applications/sencha/