# Sencha Touch Cmd tool 3.0 install not working on Mac

Tags: macos, cmd, sencha-touch-2.1

-bash: sencha: command not found

I just spent a few hours trying to make this Sencha Cmd works on my MacBook, but just couldn't. I uninstalled a previous version and just couldn't get it to work again. I always get the

-bash: sencha: command not found

error. I did try everything in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399139/install-sencha-touch-2-1-on-mac), without success.... I even get an error when I call

.bash_profile

stating that it's not found... Do you have any idea what could be the problem ?

I'm fairly new to the Linux command world so I might miss a point here. Maybe I might use "sudo" to be granted acces to bask_profile ?

EDIT : I got it working for the current bash session. I position myself at the user root (~/) and call `". .bash_profile"`(the space is important here). BUT... it only works for the current session. As soon as I close Terminal and reopen it, I loose everything :-(

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command-section-7

Comment: Hopefully my answer to an earlier question can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399139/install-sencha-touch-2-1-on-mac/14402839#14402839

Comment: @cclerville this is the exact post I used. The first one I found from a Google search. Unfortunately, I have an error message when I try .bash_profile. I think it's linked to access rights.I tried this command : export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256 >> .bash_profile But it gave me "Permission denied". Therefore, I guess I have to use sudo somewhere, but have no clue where and how....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just so you know, I managed to fix the damn thing be opening and editing the ".bash_profile" file in a text editor (TextMate for me). This is an hidden file, but you can configure your Mac to show those files in Finder. The file is located at your user's root. It is quite annoying to have to spend hour messing in path and environment variables in 2013... Installer should do those things and reports error if something happens in the install process.

Comment: +1 for `Installer should do those things and reports error if something happens in the install process.`