# Sencha touch installation on Mac OSX

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd

I've been trying to install Sencha Touch 2 on my mac but without any success.

Initially I -

1. Downloaded the latest Sencha SDK and it created a *touch-2.1.1* folder.
2. Downloaded and installed latest Sencha SDK tools 2.0.0 - Beta 3.
3. Downloaded and installed latest Sencha Cmd 3.1.0.256 for mac in the default path it was showing i.e. Users/[User-name]/bin

After this I navigated to the touch-2.1.1 folder in the terminal and typed "sencha" to check if it was working. I got the following error -

> [WARN] The current working directory
>   (/Users/administrator/Desktop/tushar/Hybrid-ness/touch-2.1.1) is not a
>   recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards
>   compatible mode.
>
> Sencha Command v2.0.0 Beta 3 Copyright (c) 2012 Sencha Inc.
>
> usage: sencha COMMAND [ARGS]
>
> The available commands are:    build          build a JSB project    create
>   bootstrapdata     generate boostrap data    create jsb            generate a
>   minimal JSB project for an app    create locale           generate a template
>   locale file from source    create manifest        generate classes manifest 
>   package           package your Touch web app into a native bundle    slice
>   theme         slice a custom theme's images for IE
>
> See 'sencha help COMMAND' for more information on a specific command.

After this I googled around and found that ONLY Sencha Cmd is needed and not Sencha SDK Tools. So I deleted the Sencha SDK Tools from /Applications *(I am ashamed of this step)*

I navigated to /Users/administrator/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256 and gave the command -

> ./sencha generate app Myapp ../MyAPp

And i was punished with

[image: this abomination]

After that I've been trying different solutions like one mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399139/install-sencha-touch-2-1-on-mac), but its still not working.

Can anyone help pls.

**PS-**

I've removed Sencha SDK tools but i'm still getting the folder reference when i do **echo $PATH**.

> /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

I did **PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin**, and checked the $PATH again then sdk tools were removed. I closed the terminal, reopened it and gave echo $PATH...this time again I could see the SDK tools path in the $PATH.

What exactly happened here???

Comment: Your PATH settings will be set probably in `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`

Comment: $HOME/.profile returns "no such file". 2nd one returns Permission denied. And What am i supposed to do with this?

Comment: You wanted to remove SDK tools from $PATH? Anyhow, the error on install is when reading `sencha.cfg` - the framework.dir directory is possibly missing. Have you checked `sencha.cfg` to see what the setting is?

Comment: @suspectus i could not open sencha.cfg. I searched for it in Finder, found 4-5 copies of it with different descriptions. But this still doesnt answer the qn.

Comment: what does the command 'which sencha' return ?

Comment: it returns `/Application/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. Install Sencha SDK tools 2.0.0 - Beta 3
2. Uninstall the tools in a clean way by running /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/uninstall
3. close and reopen shell and try the sencha command again

Comment: I can't believe I didnt try this!!! This removed the sencha sdk tools $PATH variable. I'm uninstalling everything and installing sencha touch 2 from scratch.

Comment: well technically this is just the part answer. I was just able to remove sencha sdk tools completely after this. For sencha touch 2, just download and install [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) and then the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
edit both:

*Very IMPORTANT
nano /Users/sencha/.bash_profile
nano /Users/sencha/.bashrc

## --------------

My sencha folder is: /Sencha
Default Sencha: /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/

## --------------

```
nano /Users/sencha/.bash_profile

export PATH=/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH

export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"

export PATH=/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH
#
export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"

export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH

export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"

SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/
#
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_4_0_0="/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"
#
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
nano /Users/sencha/.bashrc 

export PATH=/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH

export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"

export PATH=/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH
#
export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"

export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH

export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"

SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/
#
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_4_0_0="/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"
#
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH'
```