# -bash: sencha command not found

Tags: macos, extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

I installed Sencha SDK and Sencha command on my mac-mini and done with some sample app.. but suddenly after some time when I tried to run sencha command on terminal, I got the response as '-bash: sencha command not found', I don't know why this was happened. Earlier I didn't find such type of response but now I got this error. Please tell me what are the possible scenarios for this thing to be happened.. Thanks for your help

> Alens-Mac-mini:touch-2.2.0 SenchaTools$ sencha
>   -bash: sencha: command not found

Comment: check your `PATH`.  `echo ${PATH}`.

Comment: Take a look at my answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399139/install-sencha-touch-2-1-on-mac/14402839#14402839

Comment: I reinstalled SDK tools and Sencha cmd and then installed newer versions... thats worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should procede that way:

1. Verify if this command is contained in `PATH`. `PATH` is an environment variable holded by bash and initialized when a new user is logged in (`.bash_profile` file for all user and the corrispective into home for single user). So check what `echo $PATH` told you and verify if this command is contained into those folder
2. Probably, from step 1, the answer will be "No, it isn't". So you have to procede this way: use [`whereis`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/whereis.1.html) command to search this command (that will be an executable script) and once you find it, you have two possibilities: one is to use it directly by specifying full path (returned from `whereis` command). 
   If you want to run simply it with `sencha -arguments` you have to add executable path returned by `whereis` (`$PATH=$PATH:/returned/path/by/whereis`) into file `.bash_profile`

In that way you should be able to execute your command from any "point" in your filesystem

Comment: sencha command is not found in that folder and when I tried to find it using whereis, it didn't return any path

Comment: @smily: so I suppose that there isn't any `sencha` command into your OS.

Comment: you might have to do source ~/.bashrc if its mac so that sencha is recognized

Comment: Great info, ssinganamalla. Had the same problem for a few days! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Sencha installer expects you to use bash as shell. It fails, if you use any other (like the nice zsh). You need to copy the content of .bash_profile to your shell startup-file (.zprofile in my case), save it and open a new terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Add PATH and VAR manually in .bash_profile file at the root of your user folder,

export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/you/Path/To/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.XXX"
export PATH=/Users/you/Path/To/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.188:$PATH

Find out more about this issue at sencha forum https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?245243-Command-not-found-mac-OSX-mountain-lion